# Jenkins jUnit badge Icons

Tags: junit, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am searching for a Jenkins Plugin, to show test and test coverage badges like this:

```html
<img src="https://img.shields.io/jenkins/t/https/jenkins.qa.ubuntu.com/precise-desktop-amd64_default.svg">
```

Are there some plugins?

Thanks for help,
 Björn

Comment: Ok I found a solution for me: The Jenkins server has a REST API, so I wrote my own NodeJS Server, which get job and test information and redirect to http://shields.io